# Changing the Execute Statement key for Groovy Console in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy-console

When I open a Groovy Console in Intellij, the execute current statement key is set as <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Obviously this is very annoying as when I'm trying to write the script and trying to go to a new line it runs the script.

I've looked at the keymap in **Settings->Keymap** and it appears to be set as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Any Ideas how I can change this to actually be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found what the solution was. Turns out that the key mapping for the action that I have posted in my question was not correct action for the console I had open. Found this by actually searching for 'Execute' in the search bar of the key map dialog.

The correct mapping that I had to change was under **Settings -> Keymap -> Other -> Execute Current Statement** (picture shows changed key)

[image]

Which now is working correctly

[image]